# how to convert a URL string into an UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@UploadedImages/%@",appDel.serverUrl,[[sCatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SubCategoryIcon"]];
```

in imageName string getting the string as given below., How to convert these url to an image

http://appliicdev.xtechnologies.com/iapp/UploadedImages/5bc77bdd-3eaf-4491-813a-5aedcbfbba41.jpg

Thanks

Comment: The given URL does not have image right now. "File not found".

Comment: prob something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972555/ios-load-an-image-from-url or use something like SDWebImage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `imageWithData` from `UIImage`. Like,

```
UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageName]]];
```

Answer (score 2):

your coding is fine

change this line

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@UploadedImages/%@",appDel.serverUrl,[[sCatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SubCategoryIcon"]];
```

into bz ur `URL` contains `/UploadedImages/`

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/UploadedImages/%@",appDel.serverUrl,[[sCatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SubCategoryIcon"]];

yourimageName.image =[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageName]]];
```

will u need to load the `UIImage` in quickly` use

1. [Asynchronous FreeLoader](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Asynchronous-Freeloader)
2. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

when I try your image in browser it showing the error so check once `path is valid or not` otherwise `your image name is valid or not`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@UploadedImages/%@",appDel.serverUrl,[[sCatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SubCategoryIcon"]];
UIImage *imgObj = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:imageName]]];
_yourImgView.image=imgObj;
```